# A orderby object filter for a pure Firebase JavaScript API

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, angularjs-filter

I found `angularFire` is always confusing me when used in conjunction with the pure Firebase JavaScript API.

Let's say I have no idea how to call the Firebase datasapshot API `ss.name()`, `ss.hasChild(), ss.forEach()` etc in angularFire.

So I decide to use the Firebase JavaScript API alone because I realized it already has two-way data binding (explicit) with AngularJS without using angularFire.

[Demo without ngFire](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xm70xeXGRR5lVKxj7wBV?p=preview)

But I got a problem with the `ng-repeat`. The returned data is an object so I cannot sort. Then I found this `orderByObject` filter, but once converted to array, I would lose the object key.

Can the Firebase team help me to improve this orderByObject filter to support the object key?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `orderByPriority` to convert `firebase` objects into array and then apply normal filter and orderBy.

```
 <div ng-repeat="customer in customers | orderByPriority | filter:searchText">
     <span>{{ customer.$id }} </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: This saved my afternoon. It allowed me to use a custom filter for pagination. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the orderByPriority filter source code - which converts an object into an array ordered by the Firebase priority: https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/master/angularfire.js#L37

You can include the key of the object directly in each item in the array by setting a special `$key` property.

Comment: Hi Anant,
its ok with orderByPriority at view but what if I want to process the result before/after the view .

just like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322299/firebase-to-angularjs-object-conversion)

Comment: This is the correct answer for displaying an original key of an object after orderByPriority is applied $key and Anant fir the win!