# Dynamic ordering in AngularJS breaks when using asynchronous data

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have an AngularJS application like below. The orderBy only works if I bind it directly to hard-coded data. If I bind to the data received from the HTTP return (the commented out line), the ordering stops working.

The rating does get updated and reflected in the UI, but the dynamic ordering does not kick in. What might be the issue here? I'm using [Firebase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase) and that definitely seems to be causing some issues.

Note: The HTTP call is unauthenticated and should work for everyone.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app>
    <body >
        <div ng-controller="hotelsController" >
            <div  ng-repeat="hotel in hotels |  orderBy : 'rating' ">
                <div ng-bind="hotel.name"></div>
                <div ng-bind="hotel.rating"></div>
                <button ng-click="up(hotel)">up</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function hotelsController($scope, $http) {

                $http({method: 'GET', url:'https://blazing-fire-1297.firebaseio.com/hotels.json'}).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                    //$scope.hotels = data;

                    $scope.hotels = [{
                        name:'somethig',
                        rating: 2
                    },
                    {
                        name:'anything',
                        rating: 2
                    },
                    ];
                });

                $scope.up = function(hotel){
                    hotel.rating ++ ;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind - apparently this is an issue with Firebase and how it returns the object. To solve this issue, simply use the orderByPriority filter as available at https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/blob/master/angularfire.js#L37.

Once that filter is applied, you can then apply the other filters as usual. The orderByPriority filter converts it into an object array.

I found the solution in Stack Overflow question *[A orderby object filter for a pure Firebase JavaScript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150562)*.

Comment: Note that the 0.8 release of angularFire will have a `$asArray`, which will deprecate orderByPriority and make arrays even easier.